# Using implode in gridview yii2

Tags: yii2

I have in gridview

```
[

            'value' => function($data){
            $sum = '';
            foreach ($data->orderInfo as $request){
                $str = ($request->order_items_offer_name);


                $sum .= ($str);
            }

            return implode(',',array($sum)) ;
        }],
```

But there is no comma between data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try This:

```
[
      'value' => function($data){
              $sum = array();
              foreach ($data->orderInfo as $request){
                    $sum[] = $request->order_items_offer_name;
                }

              return implode(',',$sum);
 }],
```